Where have my posts gone?
I couldn't Upload photos and I got some replies on how to do it, but now I can't find my posts at all! Under my profile, it says I have no questions, and if I search for my user name , there is nothing either...
Help!

You posted the original question from an unregistered account with the same name. You never had both accounts merged. It’s normal that at some point you lose the connection to the unregistered account, that’s how computers work (super simplified).
The two follow-up questions were not about gardening per se, but about the mechanics of the site (how do I upload a photo / where do I get help; where is my question), which means they were migrated to Gardening and Landscaping Meta.
I very much recommend that you invest a bit of time in taking the tour and reading through the Help Center before your next post.
You still have two options:

Either contact Comunity Management to have both accounts merged
Or simply ask your original question again, including your photos as you see fit.

Personally, I would recommend the latter.
